# cordova compile android exit code 1 platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js through e;

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have tried to create the test Android application through Apache Cordova in my Windows 8.1 machine. When at the time of compile/build, I'm getting the following error message.

> E:\workspace\test4>cordova compile android --stacktrace Running
>   command: cmd "/s /c
>   "E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>   ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 Running:
>   E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>     an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>     chapter on the daemon at
>     http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read
>     the following process output to find out more:
>     ----------------------- Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Error: Could not create
>     the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred.
>     Program will exit. Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>                       throw e;
>                             ^ Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b
>   E:\workspace\test4\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true" ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to build this project Error: cmd: Command failed
>   with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\rajanipriya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

---

Below are the system variables I set:

> ANDROID_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk     ANT_HOME
>   - E:\Android\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6    JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79

For the 'PATH'system variables:

> E:\workspace\nodejs\;    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
>   E:\Android\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

---

I even installed the emulator from `'Android sdk'(extras)`